# Автонажатие TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка с классом `button primary marginBlock _participateNow`
Есть код взятый с интернета

```js
setInterval(function() {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("button primary marginBlock _participateNow");



  elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);



  if (!elements.length) return;

  elements.forEach(function(button) {

    button.click();

  });

}, 200);
```

Нужно переделать данный код для 1 нажатия. Скрипт уходил в вечное нажатие каждые 2000
Как сделать одно нажатие только?
(Скрипт сделан для TamperMonkey)

Comment: Убрать `setInterval`.

Comment: Можно готовый код? 
document.getElementsByClassName("button primary marginBlock _participateNow").click(); 
Такой вариант без всего остального tampermonkey не берет

Comment: Замените `setInterval` на `setTimeout`. Готовый код здесь не принято давать, если видно что вы не стараетесь сами решить проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, заработал :3